# How to find eigenvalues of this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How to find eigenvalues of this matrix:
 $\left(
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     2 & 0 & 0 \\
     0 & 2 & 4 \\
     0  & -1 & 2
  \end{array} \right) $

ATTEMPT:

$(2-λ) [(2-λ)(2-λ) + 4] = 0$

Comment: $(2-\lambda)[(2-\lambda)(2-\lambda) +4] = 0 $ Then expand out the brackets and solve this cubic equation for $\lambda$

Comment: I did and used the quadratic formula and got the values -8 and 2 but I think it's wrong

Comment: The first root is given by the $(2-\lambda)$ outside the square brackets, the next two roots are found by solving $\lambda^2 -4\lambda +8 =0$. You should get two complex roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the usual method

$$\det (A - \lambda I) = 0$$

that is

$$\begin{vmatrix}2-\lambda & 0 & 0\\ 0 &2- \lambda & 4 \\ 0 &-1 &2 - \lambda \end{vmatrix} = (2 - \lambda)\begin{vmatrix}2- \lambda & 4 \\ -1 &2 - \lambda \end{vmatrix} = (2 - \lambda)\Bigg((2 - \lambda)^2 + 4\Bigg) = 0$$

You can take it from here.

Comment: $(2−λ)[(λ^2 - 4λ + 8)]=0$ now do I have to use the quadratic formula?

Comment: You don't really have to. Because if $(2 - \lambda)^2 + 4 = 0$ then $(\lambda - 2)^2 = -4 \Rightarrow \lambda = 2 \pm 2i $.

Answer (score 0):

You must enclose the first $2-\lambda$ between brackets. Then equal to $0$ and solve.

Comment: like this $[(2−λ)(2−λ)(2−λ)+4] = 0$?